# Change all Class Name values orderly using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

this my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var index = -1;
var memo = ['num1','num2','num3','num4','num5','num6'];



function start() {

index = (index + 1) % memo.length ;

var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('MemoClass');

for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) { var item = cusid_ele[i]; item.innerHTML = memo[index]; }

}
</script>

<input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()">
</br>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
```

When you press START button

Each classname is given a duplicate value ,
I want the values to be given in orderly ,
So that the output when pressing START:
num1
num2
num3
num4
num5
num6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from `memo[index]` to  `memo[i];` because your index did not change in loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) { var item = cusid_ele[i]; item.innerHTML = memo[i]; }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

var index = -1;
var memo = ['num1','num2','num3','num4','num5','num6'];



function start() {

index = (index + 1) % memo.length ;

var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('MemoClass');

for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) { var item = cusid_ele[i]; item.innerHTML = memo[i]; }

}
</script>

<input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()">
</br>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) { var item = cusid_ele[i]; item.innerHTML = memo[i]; // here change from index to i
}
```

A better way can be to Foreach every span and the values in an array, put them one by one

```js
var memo = ['num1', 'num2', 'num3', 'num4', 'num5', 'num6'];
let allspans = document.querySelectorAll('.MemoClass'); // all the spans in an array

function start() {
  memo.forEach((a, post) => allspans[post].innerHTML = a) // for every value in the array, put the innerHTML of every class 
}
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()">
</br>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
</br>
<span class="MemoClass"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

change memo[index] to memo[i], so you have

```
for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) { var item = cusid_ele[i]; item.innerHTML = memo[i]; }
```